# How to see if all characters are in a variable

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm doing a hangman code and I want to display a winner text if all the characters they gave are in the word that is inserted in the beginning. So pretty much when the player guesses the word, I want to be able to display a winning text.

Here's my code so far:

```
word = input("Enter the word to guess: ")

ingame = True
guesslist = ''

while ingame == True:
    guess = str(input("Guess a letter "))
    guesslist += guess
for char in word:
    if char in guesslist:
            print(char, end=" ")

    else:
            print("_", end=" ")
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer may be to use this code here. However, your question is poor, and you've clearly not tried. For this reason, I'm not going to bother commenting because really, you should work it out yourself.

```
    class New(Exception):
        pass

    try:

        word = input("Enter the word to guess: ")

        knownLetters = []

        for letter in word:

            knownLetters.append("_")

        guesses = []
        param = " "

        while True:

            for letter in knownLetters:

                if letter == "_":

                    exit = False
                    break

                else:

                    exit = True

    if exit:

        raise New(" ")

            for letter in guesses:

                print(guesses)

            print(knownLetters)

            guess = str(input("Guess a letter {}".format(param)))

            if len (guess) != 1:

                param = "(Enter a single letter please!)"
                continue

            elif guess in guesses:

                param = "({} already tried)".format(guess)
                continue

            elif guess in word:

                guesses.append(guess)

                for letterWord, letterKnown in zip ( word, range(len(word)) ):

                    if letterWord == guess:

                        knownLetters[letterKnown] = guess

    except KeyboardInterrupt:

        print("You have lost!")

    except New:

        print("You have won!")
```